# float value in a string to int in Python

Tags: python, string

Why isn't it possible to directly convert a floating point number represented as a string in Python to an int variable?

For example,

```
>>> val=str(10.20)
>>> int(val)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.2'
```

However, this works,

```
>>> int(float(val))
10
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit jonrsharpe.

Comment: Because *"Explicit is better than implicit."* (`import this`). Explicitly converting an integer to a float is very different to quietly dropping parts of a string without warning the user that it wasn't what they expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `int` is doing two different things in your two examples.

In your first example, `int` is converting a string to an integer. When you give it `10.2`, that is not an integer so it fails.

In your second example, `int` is casting a floating point value to an integer. This is defined to truncate any fractional part before returning the integer value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this conversion if you are willing to use a third party library (full disclosure, I am the author). The [fastnumbers](https://pypi.org/project/fastnumbers) library was written for quick conversions from string types to number types. One of the conversion functions is [fast_forceint](http://fastnumbers.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#fastnumbers.fast_forceint), which will convert your string to an integer, even if it has decimals.

```
>>> from fastnumbers import fast_forceint
>>> fast_forceint('56')
56
>>> fast_forceint('56.0')
56
>>> fast_forceint('56.07')
56
```